# como mandar el valor de un for de un php a otro

Tags: php

me gustaría saber como podría mandar el valor de $sumatotal de este php a otro

```
$Sumatotal=0;
for($sum=0; $sum<12; $sum++){
    $Sumatotal+=$sumames[$sum];
    echo '<td>' . $sumames[$sum].'</td>';
}
echo '<td>' .$Sumatotal.'</td>';
```

> el valor de suma total es de 407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de este modo:

**archivo1.php**

```
$Sumatotal=0;


                       for($sum=0; $sum<12; $sum++){
                             $Sumatotal+=$sumames[$sum];
                           echo '<td>' . $sumames[$sum].'</td>';

                       }
                        echo '<td>' .$Sumatotal.'</td>';
```

**archivo2.php**

Si tratas por ejemplo de imprimir el valor de la variable `$Sumatotal` en el archivo2.php debería verse del modo siguiente

```
<?php

require 'archivo1.php';
```

Con este órden debería bastar para que se visualice el contenido de la `$Sumavariable` por que en el archivo1.php ya la estas imprimiendo con la instrucción `echo`

**EL USO DE REQUIRE**

> `REQUIRE` Me permite en este caso *requerir* el contenido de otro
>   archivo en uno nuevo, es decir al colocar esta instrucción en el
>   archivo2.php le estoy indicando que requira el contenido de
>   archivo1.php para que de este modo el código este disponible

Comment: si lo muestra pero el problema es que como se usa un data table para mostrar esa variable y otras mas manda un error no hay otra forma de mandar ese valor?